# Is there a way to select Maria Db table row that has json values column together with other columns where* a condition is met in the Json

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.1

Using the Sample of json values attached below , im unable to select all attributes of the json where **receivedstatus='YES'** and those that **receivedstatus='No'** not to show up .

```json
[
  {
    "itemCode": "LAB-BIOCHEM-0007",
    "serviceName": "Blood Gas Test",
    "qty": "1",
    "rate": "5000.0",
    "total": "5000.0",
    "classification": "",
    "department": "LABORATORY",
    "inputDate": "2023-02-09",
    "paymentStatus": "",
    "receivedStatus": "YES",
    "processed": "",
    "cmTotal": "0.0",
    "receivingUsername": "",
    "processingUsername": "",
    "approvalStatus": "",
    "specimen": "",
    "doctorsRequestingName": ""
  },
  {
    "itemCode": "LAB-SEROL-001",
    "serviceName": "Anc Profile",
    "qty": "1",
    "rate": "3000.0",
    "total": "3000.0",
    "classification": "",
    "department": "LABORATORY",
    "inputDate": "2023-02-09",
    "paymentStatus": "",
    "receivedStatus": "NO",
    "processed": "",
    "cmTotal": "0.0",
    "receivingUsername": "",
    "processingUsername": "",
    "approvalStatus": "",
    "specimen": "",
    "doctorsRequestingName": ""
  },
  {
    "itemCode": "LAB-PARAS-001",
    "serviceName": "B/S For Mps",
    "qty": "1",
    "rate": "200.0",
    "total": "200.0",
    "classification": "",
    "department": "LABORATORY",
    "inputDate": "2023-02-09",
    "paymentStatus": "",
    "receivedStatus": "YES",
    "processed": "",
    "cmTotal": "0.0",
    "receivingUsername": "",
    "processingUsername": "",
    "approvalStatus": "",
    "specimen": "",
    "doctorsRequestingName": ""
  },
  {
    "itemCode": "LAB-MICROB-012",
    "serviceName": "Hvs Wet Prep And Gram Stain ",
    "qty": "1",
    "rate": "500.0",
    "total": "500.0",
    "classification": "",
    "department": "LABORATORY",
    "inputDate": "2023-02-09",
    "paymentStatus": "",
    "receivedStatus": "NO",
    "processed": "",
    "cmTotal": "0.0",
    "receivingUsername": "",
    "processingUsername": "",
    "approvalStatus": "",
    "specimen": "",
    "doctorsRequestingName": ""
  }
]
```

I tried running the following Query but it is returning all the values whether **received status is yes or not**

```sql
Select
  *
from (
  SELECT distinct
    patient_name,
    age,
    visit_no,
    sex,
    laboratory_requests,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_EXTRACT(
        t.laboratory_requests,
        CONCAT('$[', x.seq, '].department')
      )
    ) AS department,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_EXTRACT(
        t.laboratory_requests,
        CONCAT('$[', x.seq, '].receivedStatus')
      )
    ) AS receivedStatus
  FROM
    pb_doctors_requests t
    INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT seq FROM seq_0_to_10
    ) AS x ON
    JSON_EXTRACT(
      t.laboratory_requests,
      CONCAT('$[', x.seq, ']')
    ) IS NOT NULL
) as s
where receivedStatus in ('NO');
```

[image]

Comment: What exact version of MariaDB is used?. What would be the expected result of the query?.

Comment: Maria Version '10.3.37-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1